# How to reset root password on Linux? Just getting the NOOBS window

Tags: linux, root, raspbian

I have a Linux computer, and I recently needed the root password to my system. When I got the computer, I didn't know the root password, and currently need to reset it. I'm thinking I would need to boot it in a recovery mode, and run a command. When I hit <kbd>shift</kbd> on my system's splash screen when I start the computer, it opens a NOOBS window, but I'm not sure what to do from there.

For reference, this is what's in `/etc/os-release`.

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

My Linux kernel release is 4.14.79-v7+.

Comment: this advise predates NOOBS but may be worth a try: https://linux.tips/tutorials/how-to-boot-raspberry-pi-into-single-user-mode

Comment: And to accompany the link from @FrankThomas check out this thread on the [Raspberry Pi SE site](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/3751/26557).

Comment: ok, so on reread, I may have been distracted by the NOOBs and the general change to raspbian that might prevent single-user mode access. if that is the case I apologize. When you boot into raspbian, do you have sudo access?

Comment: @FrankThomas No, that's why I need the root pwd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by using the following steps:

1. Press <kbd>shift</kbd> on the splash screen to go into the NOOBS window.
2. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to go into "Edit Config"
3. Instead of `config.txt`, open the `cmdline.txt` file.
4. Add `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt`.
5. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit NOOBS. You boot in a command line.
6. Run `su root`.
7. Run `sudo passwd root`.
8. Follow the prompts.
9. Restart the computer.
10. Follow steps 1-3 again.
11. Remove `init=/bin/sh` at the end of `cmdline.txt`.
12. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> to exit NOOBS. Your normal computer boots.

Answer (score -1):

You have access to the system and the shell. That's point A. You drive down the road to NOOB. That's point B. And there you get stuck.

My answer was saying: Try to solve the problem at point A with resetting root password via command line with:

```
sudo passwd root
```

Comment: Your [original answer](https://superuser.com/a/1728288/167207) was deleted because it is basically a comment and not a definitive answer. That said, you need to earn at leas 50 rep to comment. So that’s that.

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I dont have sudo access until I find my root password. @ThomasAnderson